# Change translation after release

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring

I have been looking for it for quite a while without finding the good keywords on Google...

I have some Localized.strings files in my app main bundle. But sometimes, I find some mistakes reading them right after Apple submitted my new version to the App Store.

Do I always need to generate a new version of the app with the corrected .strings files and then wait for another submission?

Isn't there an easier and faster way to do it?

Comment: why don't you make the localized strings come from your server? that way you can ensure they are always correct?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, iOS app only take 24 hours for review. I won't be take so much time for update the new translation. 
Although, you can have a new way to handle the translation:

1. Use can put your localize file on the server and handle in the app.
2. You can use https://www.oneskyapp.com/ to keep your localize file
   then update in the app.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know OneSkyApp but seeing there "iOS tutorial" integration makes me want to close the window before starting everything. I think I'll just go on with the old Localized.strings way...